# ClassList not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
$(e.target).siblings().classList[2]
```

I'm getting this error:

> Unable to get value of the property '2': object is null or undefined

Comment: did you check what's in `classList`? maybe there's only 0/1, and no 2

Comment: That's because `classList` is not supported by IE9 ([Can I use?](http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist)).

Comment: any fix for this to work in IE9

Answer (score 1):

`classList` [is not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) in IE9. You can use this:

```
$(e.target).siblings().each(function()
{
    var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    var myClass = classes[2];
});
```

Comment: _.each($(e.target).siblings(), function(child, index){
         
           var classes = child.attr("class").split(" ");
           var myClass = classes[2]; getting error child.attr is not a function

Comment: Because `child.attr` is not a function... In the code you're using `child` is a `DOMElement` not a `jQuery` object. That's why I used `$(this).attr`. You can use `$(child).attr` if you really need `child`.